# Jquery: Add class unless there is a child of certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do an addclass, but only if it doesn't have a child of a certain class.

```
$selector.addClass('addthisclass');
```

So I want:

```
<div class="addthisclass"><span></span></div>
```

And nothing on here.

```
<div><span class="badclass"></span></div>
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`:has`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/has#selector) and [`:not`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not#selector) selectors:

```
$("div:not(:has(span.badclass))").addClass("addthisclass");
```

Comment: He 'doesn't' want it to be added if it has bad class.

Comment: Didn't know about the :has selector.  Nice!

Comment: oh I must of hit the page between the time you edited it and the time you posted.  lol

Comment: @drs9222, he  didn't have the :not at first.

Comment: That is one crazy selector if you ask me.  Exactly how deep does the jquery rabbit hole go?

Comment: @Yogi - coming around to that point of view more and more as of late.

Comment: Absolutely. In fact, I just registered jqueryrocks.com and will start posting snippets like this on that site. :)